# Unable to delete folders using DOS command

Tags: command, dos

I have been trying to delete a folder structure present in Windows XP using DOS command.
Root folder A has two folders B and C and a file F1. Folders B and C have files F2 and F3 respectively. I am executing the command RD /s /q C:\XYZ\A from the command prompt so as to delete the folder A and all its contents. On doing so I am getting the error as folders B and C cannot be accessed as they are being used by some other process. Howevere files F1, F2 and F3 have been deleted by the above command. If I again execute the above command then the fodlers B and C gets deleted but A remains. On executing the command for the third time, folder A also gets deleted.
Same scenario works fine on another machine in just one attempt.
Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue.
Thanks in advance
Regards,
Arpit

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the RD command. It's that something else is accessing a folder and/or file during the delete process.

Make sure there are no running programs that could be the culprit, explorer windows open inside the directory (although this may not cause an error) and that you're not running the command from a dos prompt that's inside the folder structure.

I don't think anyone will be able to give much more insight since it's going to be machine / installed applications specific.